# Can't post new question - "Review your question" button breaks page

Tags: bug, asking-questions

I just noticed the new "Review your question" button in the new question page. I believe it's some kind of A/B test.

I am trying to post a question. When I click the button, the page takes a while loading (5 seconds) and then I get Chrome's "Oh Snap" error page. (also, more importantly, my question is not being posted).